# Javascript variable is an array of objects but can't access the elements

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase database and Javascript, and I have code that will get each question in each category. I have an object called category will contain the name, the questions, and the question count, then it will be pushed into the list of categories (questionsPerCategory). Inside the the callback function I just do `console.log(questionsPerCategory)`. It prints the object (array) that contains the categories and questions. Now my problem is that when I do `console.log(questionsPerCategory[0])` is says it's *undefined*, I also tried `console.log(questionsPerCategory.pop())` since it's an array but it's also *undefined*. Why is that? Below is the code and the image of the console log. Additional note: CODE A and C are asynchronous, CODE B and D are synchronous.

[image]

```
this.getQuestionsForEachCategory = function(callback, questions, questionsPerCategory) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('category');
    var questionRef = firebase.database().ref('question');
    console.log('get questions for each category');

    // CODE A
    ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {

        // CODE B
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var key = childSnapshot.key;

            var childData = childSnapshot.val();

            var category = {
                category_name: childData.category_name
            };

            // CODE C               
            questionRef.orderByChild("category_name").equalTo(childData.category_name).once("value", function(questionSnapshot){
                var count = 0;
                var q = [];

                // CODE D
                questionSnapshot.forEach(function(childQuestionSnapshot) {
                    var questionObj = childQuestionSnapshot.val();
                    count++;

                    questions.push(questionObj.question);
                    q.push(questionObj.question);
                });

                category.questions = q;
                category.questionCount = count;
                questionsPerCategory.push(category);

            });

        });
        callback(questionsPerCategory); 

    });
};
```

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle/jsbin that reproduces the minimal problem?

Comment: can you show the callback function where you put "console.log(questionsPerCategory[0])"?

Comment: This is due to asynchronous call. You jut check the below link.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967782/firebase-realtim‌​e-data-in-not-gettin‌​g-added-properly-in-‌​scope-variable-angul‌​arjs/3911035](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967782/firebase-realtim%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Be-data-in-not-gettin%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bg-added-properly-in-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bscope-variable-angul%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Barjs/3911035)

Comment: @JoeyEtamity It's really just a console log

Comment: @ti2005 The code you provided there, is it using underscore.js? I searched about the _(recvCategories) and _.filter and found that it might  be underscore.js

Comment: @Zik In that code snippet i'm using lodash.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `callback(questionsPerCategory);` should happen when all *async* calls are finished.

Right now the `questionsPerCategory` is not ready when the *callback* is called.
I would use `Promise API` to accomplish this.

Depending on the `Promise` library you are using, this can be accomplished in a different ways, e.g. by using [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) it looks like you need [map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) functionality.

Comment: What do you mean not ready? So the callback must happen after the ref.once(..)? Anyway, I used a promise and it now works. (I use angularjs for promises) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
this.getQuestionsForEachCategory = function(callback, questions) {
var ref = firebase.database().ref('category');
var questionRef = firebase.database().ref('question');
console.log('get questions for each category');
var questionsPerCategory = [];
// CODE A
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {

    // CODE B
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var key = childSnapshot.key;

        var childData = childSnapshot.val();

        var category = {
            category_name: childData.category_name
        };

        // CODE C               
        questionRef.orderByChild("category_name").equalTo(childData.category_name).once("value", function(questionSnapshot){
            var count = 0;
            var q = [];

            // CODE D
            questionSnapshot.forEach(function(childQuestionSnapshot) {
                var questionObj = childQuestionSnapshot.val();
                count++;

                questions.push(questionObj.question);
                q.push(questionObj.question);
            });

            category.questions = q;
            category.questionCount = count;
            questionsPerCategory.push(category);

        });
    callback(questionsPerCategory); 
    });
});
};
```