# Can't take information from an array ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I can't map an array .First I did push some objects in the array

```
const resultat = [];
resultat.push(object);
```

after that when I did console the array it containes the objects correctly

this the result of console of the array

```
[]
0: { user: {…}, name: "Test User 1", private: null, sharingspace: {…}}
1: { user: {…}, name: "FoodTest  ", private: null, sharingspace: {…}}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

and when I did the map it didn't take any informations I tried to console resultat[0] but it returned undefined.

it's like the problem of this article [Javascript variable is an array of objects but can't access the elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119658/javascript-variable-is-an-array-of-objects-but-cant-access-the-elements)

I added the information by looping on axios and fullfilling the object

```
//this is the part where I stored the data 
import { SET_SHARINGSPACES, SHARING_LOADING, CLEAR_SHARING } from "./types";
import axios from "axios";

export const setSharingSpaces = (org, user) => dispatch => {
  const orgName = org.value.substr(1);
  const groups = user.group.filter(group => group.includes(orgName));
  const resultat = [];
  dispatch(SharingLoading());
  groups.forEach(function(group, index) {
    let idparts = group.split("#");
    let aBox = "a" + orgName;
    axios
      .get("api/" + aBox + "/group/" + aBox + ":" + idparts[1])
      .then(res => resultat.push(res.data[0]));
  });
  dispatch(setSharing(resultat));
};
export const setSharing = res => {
  return {
    type: SET_SHARINGSPACES,
    payload: res
  };
};
// Graph loading
export const SharingLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: SHARING_LOADING
  };
};
// Graph loading
export const clearSharing = () => {
  return {
    type: CLEAR_SHARING
  };
};
```

Here I charge the component when the data is loaded

```
const { groups, loading } = this.props.sharingSpace;

    let SharingContent;
    if (groups == null || loading) {
      SharingContent = <h4>0 Spaces</h4>;
    } else {
      SharingContent = <SharingList groups={groups} />;
    }
```

and here the component to use the data

```
class SharingList extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { groups } = this.props.sharingSpace;
    console.log("group", groups);
    const names = groups.map(group => group.sharingspace.name);
    console.log(names);

    return (
      <List component="div" disablePadding>
        <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
          <ListItemText inset primary="Space 1" />
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    );
  }
}
SharingList.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  sharingSpace: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  sharingSpace: state.sharingSpace
});
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {}
)(withStyles(styles)(SharingList));
```

Comment: Can you share a fiddle? @Zouari

Comment: I didn't understand u what do u mean exactly

Comment: share the code on https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @zouari please share your code

Comment: @Sohan I just added the code

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda hard to answer based on the information provided.

But since you are mentioning axios and that it "shows" with `console.log`, it might be a race effect.

This means that your data is not there yet, thus the `[]` empty array when you `console.log` it, and the results when you expand it - Chrome is doing some 'magic' to populate the array with the newest data available, even if at the time of the `console.log` it was empty.

So if you directly `console.log` the first element of your array, it will try to actually display the first element, which is not there yet, thus showing nothing.

It's also indicated by this small "i" icon there (you can hover it in your console) :

[image: i icon]